# How to create custom id in java with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Hello i am writing an small program in java/spring/mysql that require custom id for an entity. I was looking arround to find a solution, but i can't seem to find it. Is there a standard way for doing this in java with mysql.

Example :

```
id = MDF18-001, MDF18-002, etc
```

Where 18 is the year, and 001 is a counter that reset each year

Thank you

Comment: You're looking for a *standard* way of generating a *custom* ID?

Comment: Shmosel, if there is one i would like to know it

Comment: Just create a new column in your SQL table with title "cID" of type varchar and set it as your primary key in the tables using a SQL IDE. Then whenever you add a new row into your table, generate the value for cID in your java before executing your SQL statement. Pretty easy to do.

Comment: Shn_Android, by doing so, how is the java know which number to increment the counter if many user can generate new entity?  i have to check the last entered row in the db then increament it?